# Parse Livequery NSPredicate issue

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am building a chat application using Livequery. The chat works well with:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"itemID = '\(itemId1)' OR itemID = '\(itemId2)'")
query = Message.query(with: predicate)?.order(byAscending: "createdAt")
let query = PFQuery(className: MY_CLASS_NAME, predicate: predicate)
```

This works well if I don't use live queries and pull with time interval.
Livequery also works if I don't add predicate.

Below is the error I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (PFQuery)'

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is because the type in where clause is pointer.